# Cant use toLocaleString in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've created a util lib to format a number.

this is the format lib

```
module.exports = {
  format: function (number) {
    let value = number.toString()
    let teste = value.slice(0, -2) + '.' + value.slice(-2)
    let newvalue = Number(teste)
    return newvalue.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
  }
}
```

in my file I import it ant use:

```
var format = require('../utils/format').format
let number = format(31231)
```

But it doesnt return the correct format `R$2.312,31`
Its returning `R$2,312.31`

If I run in JsFiddle its works as expected...Dont know what can be wrong

Comment: I believe this may help: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like a [bug in node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8433) - you could correct with

```js
const reformat = s => s.replace(/[,.]/g, x => ({'.':',', ',':'.'})[x]);

console.log(reformat('R$2,312.31'))
```

You might also want to place a guard on the replacement:

```
s => /\.\d{2}$/.test(s) ? s.replace(/[,.]/g, x => ({'.':',', ',':'.'})[x]) : s
```

Use it in your lib like this:

```
module.exports = {
  format: function (number) {
    let value = number.toString()
    let teste = value.slice(0, -2) + '.' + value.slice(-2)
    let newvalue = Number(teste)
    const reformat = s => /\.\d{2}$/.test(s) ? s.replace(/[,.]/g, x => ({'.':',', ',':'.'})[x]) : s
    return reformat(newvalue.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }))
  }
}
```